# How to exclude the sub directory using URL rewrite rules?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2012

I have hosted my application on Default site(www.mysite.com) and I have created few web application under Default site(www.mysite.com/car, www.mysite.com/bike and www.mysite.com/ship). I have written URL rewrite rule for my default site to serve from one of my sub application(www.mysite.com/ship) like below image

[image]

But, now the problem was my other sub applications not loading. How can I exclude my sub applications(www.mysite.com/bike) using URL rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the rule is below
Your rule matches for all the cases because the pattern is (.*), so if someone comes in with the url mysite.com/bike/somehting or mysite.com/car/somehting then .* matches with bike  or car and is rewritten as mysite.com/ship/bike/somehting or mysite.com/ship/car/somehting.

You need to finetune the rule based on specific requirements you have.
For eg if you want to rewrite or redirect all the requests which doesn't come with anything after the hostname to ship then have pattern as ^$ which is matches empty or nothing, this will atch for url's like mysite.com and select rewrite option as redirect and client will be redirected to mysite.com/ship

2) Or within conditions you can add something like REQUEST_URI does not match car/.* AND REQUEST_URI does not match bike/.*
This will make sure it works with all other url's which doesn't come in with car or bike and will add ship to that url while rewriting

Answer (score 0):

Lot of ways to solve this.  One quick way would be to open the URL Rewrite config for car/bike/ship app and disable/remove the rule at that level.  IIS Manager -> Sites -> Default Web Site -> Bike.  Open URL Rewrite Feature, select the rule, then click remove.